# How to get all middle names In a name

Tags: swift4

Say, I have the following fullnames:

1) Whitney Rajakanya SiriVana Giovendi

2) Cheryl Thompson Winston

How to retrieve the middlename from the above respective fullname?

**Example:** 
There are 2 middle names in name (1), and there is one middle name in name(2)

I used this code but it didn't get the middle name.

```
var components = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")
if(components.count > 0)
{
    let firstName = components.removeFirst()
}
```

**Problem**:

1) How get all the middle names in a name? Some names have 1 or more (like shown above).

Thanks

Comment: inferring full names is a bit of a pain and usually error prone (prefixes and suffixes can be numerous as well), with that said. if you can logically say the first word in the array is the first name, and the last word in the array in the last name, then everything else is a middle name.

Comment: @Brett Caswell, I need a flexible func that can handle long fullname which can be 3 words or 4 words or longer after spliting the fullname. How to get middlename if some have 1 or 2 or 3 middlename?  I know the first and the Last but How to handle when fullname have 1 or 2 or more middlename?

Comment: Assuming that names can be separated at blanks is dangerous, if not plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define "middle name" as everything except the first and last word in a name, then you can split the string by spaces, `dropFirst` and `dropLast`, then join the result.

```
var components = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")

if (components.count <= 2) {
    // no middle name
} else {
    let middleName = components.dropFirst().dropLast().joined(separator: " ")
}
```

You can also make use of [`PersonNameComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/personnamecomponentsformatter) if the names are from various locales and you need different ways of handling each of them.

Comment: It seems there is no output when run this code. I got error: use of unresolved identifier 'middleName

Comment: @MilkBottle You are right. If you want to see the middle name as output, add a `print` in the `else` branch. `middleName` is only in scope in the `else` branch.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a greedy reg-exp and get the middle names easily, like:

```
let namesArray = ["Whitney Rajakanya SiriVana Giovendi", "Cheryl Thompson Winston", "James T. Kirk", "Jean-Luc Picard", "J. Archer"]

if let regExp = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: " (.*) ", options: .caseInsensitive) {

    namesArray.forEach { (name) in
        regExp.matches(in: name, options: .reportProgress, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: name.count)).forEach({ (textCheckingResult) in
            guard textCheckingResult.numberOfRanges > 1 else { return }
            let middleNames = (name as NSString).substring(with: textCheckingResult.range(at: 1))
            debugPrint("\(middleNames)")
        })
    }
}
```

then you can see the middle names printed out, like:

```
Rajakanya SiriVana
Thompson
T.
```

that could be a clean and sleek solution.

---

***NOTE:** logically it is not clear whether the shortened middle names should be filtered out or not, but you can get the gist and will be able to extend this concept at your convenince.*

Comment: The middlename is taken out from a fullname in which a space is used as a separator like my Example. your fullname like James T. Kirk will be James T Kirt without a period. can you show me how to change the regExp and handling only one fullname at a time and not names in an array. Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle, none of the changes, you need, require anything special knowledge – removing the array or removing the dots are fairly straightforward tasks and fundamentally changes nothing in the concept, I'm sure you can amend these easily and make it matching your requirement in no time :)